# ExtJS 4 - Scrollbar display issues in chrome with a google maps instance and grid in a border layout together

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, google-maps-api-3, extjs4, scrollbar

I'm using ExtJS 4 and I have a viewport with a border layout.  The center region contains a panel while the south region contains a grid. When the panel is rendered it has a google maps instance rendered to its body.  I've made the south region (grid) collapsible.

This all works and looks fine, but when you collapse the south region, the grid's scrollbars are not hidden.  They hide momentarily as the grid is animating the collapse, but after that they reappear.  This problem occurs in Chrome but does not occur in Firefox.

See my jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WUeWb/4/

If you un-comment out line 82, preventing the map from being rendered, everything works fine.  So there is definitely something related to the google maps instance that is messing things up, but I can't figure out what it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's a jsFiddle using the GMapPanel extension: http://jsfiddle.net/WUeWb/5/.  Scrollbar problem persists.

Thanks!

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux/');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    'Ext.ModelManager',
    'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager']);

Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

    Ext.define('ForumThread', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'title', 'forumtitle', 'forumid', 'username', {
            name: 'replycount',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'lastpost',
            mapping: 'lastpost',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'timestamp'
        },
            'lastposter', 'excerpt', 'threadid'],
        idProperty: 'threadid'
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: 50,
        model: 'ForumThread',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-browse-remote.php',
            reader: {
                root: 'topics',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        }
    });

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        height: 300,
        title: 'Grid in south panel - ' + Ext.getVersion().version,
        store: store,
        loadMask: true,
        columns: [{
            text: "Topic",
            dataIndex: 'title',
            width: 200
        }, {
            text: "Author",
            dataIndex: 'username',
            width: 300
        }, {
            text: "Replies",
            dataIndex: 'replycount',
            width: 370
        }, {
            text: "Last Post",
            dataIndex: 'lastpost',
            width: 650
        }],
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store
        }),
        region: 'south',
        collapsible: true
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        items: [{
            region: 'center',
            title: 'Center panel',
            listeners: {
                boxready: function (t) {
                    //return; //uncomment this to prevent map from being added.  grid will then collapse correctly
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 2,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                    };
                    t.gmap = new google.maps.Map(t.body.dom, myOptions);
                },
                resize: function (t) {
                    if (Ext.isDefined(t.gmap)) {
                        google.maps.event.trigger(t.gmap, 'resize');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        grid]
    });

    store.loadPage(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using google map javascript directly when ExtJS already have one for that? If you use `Ext.ux.GMapPanel`, there will be no need to listen resize and boxready events. GMAP class already have `mapready` and resize events; and if there is any need to use native events of google map, you can use them by this: 
let your instance name of map is `myMap`, then `myMap.gmap` is the orignal map to fire events.

try using

```
items: [{
        region: 'center',
        title: 'Center panel',
        items : { xtype : 'gmappanel',
          center : {
          lat : 38.410558,
          lng : -98.525391
          }
         }
        }]
```

Comment: Same problem here but instead of GMap i use an iframe which displays a webpage...